# Inserting date into SQL table using Python

Tags: python, sql

The following code isn't working - it correctly inserts the 'NumberOfUnitsSold' column, but the 'date' column just ends up being 0000-00-00. I'm sure it's just something simple I'm doing wrong.

```
currentDate = 9/12/14
currentDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(currentDate, '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RealSalesData (date, NumberOfUnitsSold) VALUES (%s, 1)" % currentDate)
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like I might need to use TO_DATE() or something, but I haven't been successful at making that work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

currentDate  = "9/12/14"

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using string interpolation to build your query like that. Whatever sql library you're using should support parameterized queries, where you pass the querystring with placeholders intact and supply the values separately for the library to put in. This protects against SQL injection attacks. As an added bonus, you don't need to worry about formatting issues such as yours.

It should probably look something like:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO RealSalesData (date, NumberOfUnitsSold) VALUES (?, 1)", currentDate)
```

Comment: Usually, cursors use `?` as the placeholder.